# If the boundary of a bounded open set is a manifold, what is its dimension?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a *bounded* open set and suppose that the topological boundary $\partial \Omega = \bar \Omega \setminus \Omega$ has the structure of a topological manifold. In particular, $\partial \Omega$ has a dimension $m$. Can we say anything about $m$; is it $m=n-1$, as intuition suggests?

Comment: Maybe related [Hausdorff dimension of the boundary of an open set in the Euclidean space - lower bound](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40593)?

Comment: @Invisible The discussion there is promising, what it shows is that $\Omega$ has Hausdorff dimension at least $n-1$. However, Hausdorff dimension is generally $\geq$ topological dimension. Is there any way to conclude something about the topological dimension?

Comment: An open set in $\Bbb R^n$ always has dimension $n$, this is well-known. Its boundary has dimension $\le n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where your set is convex, you may want to take a a look at chapters 6 and 18 of '*Rockafellar, Ralph Tyrell. Convex analysis.*' Essentially you can show that the relative boundary of a convex set $A$ is also the union of all proper faces of that set and that proper faces are convex subsets of $A$ that are exactly the intersection of $A$ with an affine space of lower dimension. Finally if the interior of $A$ is non empty, the relative interior and the interior match and so the relative boundary is actually the boundary.

Not sure if that can help for the general case.